# Incompatible Pointer Types in C

Tags: c, structure

I have been messing around with this for some time now but I still get the same warning:

```
"incompatible pointer types passing 'char *[15]' to parameter of type 'char *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]:
strncpy(person->firstName, fn[j], NAME_SIZE - 1);"
```

The source code in question is:

```
while (i < numPersons) {
    j = rand() % NUM_NAMES;
    person->firstName[NAME_SIZE - 1] = "\0";
    strncpy(person->firstName, fn[j], NAME_SIZE - 1);
    j = rand() % NUM_NAMES;
    person->familyName[NAME_SIZE - 1] = "\0";
    strncpy(person->familyName, sn[j], sizeof(person->familyName) - 1);
    if (rand() % 2) {
        person->emplyeeOrStudent = 1;
        populateStudent(&person->stu);
    } else {
        populateEmployee(&person->emp);
        person->emplyeeOrStudent = 0;
    }
    person++;
    i++;
}
```

This is for the structure person:

```
struct Person{
    char *firstName[15];
    char *familyName[15];
    char *telephone[10];
    union combine comb;
    unsigned int emplyeeOrStudent:1;
};
```

Comment: show the structure `person`

Comment: what's `fn` and `sn`?

Comment: i think person->firstName[NAME_SIZE - 1] = "\0"; -> person->firstName[NAME_SIZE - 1] = '\0';

Comment: In the call to `strncpy`, you can't pass `person->firstName`, you need to index into it.  You probably intended `person->firstName[NAME_SIZE - 1]`, except that won't work either since it points to a string literal which cannot be modified (and is too small).

Comment: I suspect you mean for your `struct` to be `struct Person{ char firstName[15]; char familyName[15]; char telephone[10]; ... };`

Comment: @TomKarzes That did the trick, thank you!

Comment: @NickK That silenced the warning, let's see what happens when you run...

Comment: It's really not understandable why someone would use `char *firstName[15]`

Comment: You most probably want `char firstName[15]`..or `char* firstName`.

Comment: Are you trying to allow a `Person` to have 15 different `firstName` ? Or did you really want `struct Person{
    char firstName[15];
.....` ? i.e. to allow one name of maximum 14 characters

Answer (score 1):

when you pass person->firstName you basically pass char** instead of char*
second - if person is not pre allocated your copy will failed cause you can't copy to char* field which is allocated on data segment and is basically const!